# Not able to bind textview to a static method from a publicly non instantiable final class

Tags: java, android, mvvm, data-binding, android-databinding

I want to bind one of my utils class to a textview. I included my Utils class in data field. When I run the app I am getting error like the method is not found

My xml file

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


        <data>
            <import type="PACKAGE_NAME.utils.CommonUtils"/>
            <variable
                name="viewModel"
                type="PACKAGE_NAME.PACKAGE_UI_PATH.RecordItemViewModel" />

        </data>

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14.5sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:textColor="#66000000"
                android:id="@+id/dateTv"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="4.5sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@{CommonUtils.returnDiffFromCurrentDate(viewModel.mDate)}
"               tools:text="1 day ago"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    </layout>
```

And my utility file is

```
public final class CommonUtils {

    private CommonUtils() {
        // This utility class is not publicly instantiable
    }


    public static String returnDiffFromCurrentDate(long givenTime)
    {
        long timeGap = System.currentTimeMillis() - givenTime;
        return String.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(timeGap));
    }
}
```

I got the following erroe message

Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:cannot find method returnDiffFromCurrentDate(java.lang.String) in class PACKAGE_NAME.utils.CommonUtils

Comment: Have you provided correct package name?

Comment: @NancyY yes. The package is name is correct. The issue is in accessing the method

Comment: What type is viewModel.mDate? The error says it can not find a method called returnDiffFromCurrentDate with a single String parameter, not long as it is in your CommonUtils class

Comment: @RubénViguera you are right. Thanks for the help. The mDate is String and that is the reason it shows the error

Comment: I've made an answer. Please feel free to mark it as accepted answer if it really was helpfull for you

Comment: @RubénViguera sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it can not find a method called returnDiffFromCurrentDate with a single String parameter, not long as it is in your CommonUtils class.

The problem then is in viewModel.mDate what seems to be a String, and not a long

You should use any other method in order to transform it to a long or change returnDiffFromCurrentDate to expect a String